# Hot Reload Crashes React native app (ios)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm making a react native app, i face an issue whenever i save or i press R to reload the application, it crashes with error EXC_CRASH(SIGABRT)

**React Native Version**: 0.72.4

**Crash Logs:**
[image]